# List Threshold limit

Tags: list, list-view-threshold

I have a list of 28000 items, i imported it in sharepoint using the Import App, but the issue is it wont allow me to do anything, i cannot create index on columns, cannot create a view or filter items.
I received this error when I tried creating index

> Sorry, something went wrong The attempted operation is prohibited
>   because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the
>   administrator.Operations that exceed the list view threshold are
>   allowed in the following time window defined by the administrator: 
>   Daily, from  10:00:00 PM to 1:00:00 AM .

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: what is the sharepoint version?

Comment: If you want to use indexing, you'd need to create the list first and set up the columns you want indexed, then add your data.  The problem you'll run into with the import app is that you'll break the 5k threshold and once you do that you can't set up any indexes.  I guess you could split the file and just import a portion of it which is under the 5k, setup the indexes, then paste in the rest of the data.  That would at least avoid you having to manually create the columns and would still allow you to setup the indexes.

Comment: Thank You Nate!, your answer helped me too but not sure how to mark it or vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The List View threshold is set per web application within Central Admin. If you navigate to Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Web Applications > Select your Web App > General Settings > Resource Throttling.

[This technet link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc262787.aspx) outlines the software boundaries for SharePoint, although I would contest that above 30,000 items, lists can become a little "shaky", in my personal experience. Thus I would being splitting out your list if at all possible.

EDIT: If you do not have admin access, contact your administrator citing the above information.

Comment: Your administrator can also change the daily window to a time that you'd be able to work but I would do it on the edge of business hours (say 5-6pm). You're still going to run into the problem that users won't be able to see list views because there are more than 5000 items. Your administrator can index columns, or you can do it during the daily window. You can use these indexed columns to create views with 5000 or fewer items (or whatever threshold you set using George's answer.

Comment: I'm just wondering Is it permissible to change the list view threshold limit? i read many threads, blogs which advise not to change. I'm cutting down the list by 10K items but i still face the same error. I'm in dilemma of moving the limit size. This is SharePoint 2013 On premises and i do not have access to Central Admin.

Comment: Given that the limit for Administrators and Auditors is set to 20000, I couldn't see that this would cause an issue. But if you don't have access to central admin, and your administrator is unwilling to change the list view threshold, then you really don't have any other option, other than bring the list item count beneath 5000 I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your limitations of your Import App, but perhaps the best solution for a large number of list items is to use an Excel spreadsheet instead.  Perhaps a SharePoint list is not the BestToolForTheJob(tm).

Answer (score 0):

Please dont do this to SharePoint. If you are expecting such a large amount of list Items then do plan first.

My suggestions would be to,

1. create more column index
2. create views with filters i.e. set filters not only on the default view but also on other views so that the number of retrieved elements is limited i.e. always less than 5000 elements (list threshold) are retrieved.
3. In case of Document libraries as well, build document structure using [folders](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16166.sharepoint-2013-using-folders.aspx) -> location based metadata!
4. Archive the old entries, set archiving schedule...

There are certainly other settings as well. 
BTW I had this problem a number of times and everytime I ended up building a SharePoint Search driven solution for that.

Answer (score -2):

The "Site Collection Administrator" has a larger list view threshold.  The person with those rights should be able to define those indexed columns.  They can also set the default view to limit items returned (no datasheet view).

**Edit:** Comment below indicates the above information is wrong.  I am both Farm and SC admin and admit I may have gotten it wrong.  So, please try the above advice and replace "Site Collection" with "Farm".

Comment: The Site Collection Administrator has the same limitations as any other non-Farm Administrator user.